# How can I use python requests to get information from lowerquality's gentle?

Tags: python-3.x, windows, python-requests

Using Windows 10 and Python 3.8.6

So there's a program called gentle (https://hub.docker.com/r/lowerquality/gentle) which I can run as a localhost site. You input an audio file and a transcription of that file, and Gentle outputs the time stamps for each word and phoneme.

With curl, you would typically command: `curl -F "audio=@audio.mp3" -F "transcript=@words.txt" "http://localhost:8765/transcriptions?async=false"`

But pycURL isn't compatible with windows 10, from what I've seen. People suggest I use requests instead!

**How would I phrase a request in python** indicating the files I want analyzed, and have gentle return the speech information? I'm relatively new to requests!

Comment: Have you read the documentation for ```requests?```

Answer (score 0):

If you are on windows and cannot access this localhost through requests then you must turn off the proxy set by Microsoft for localhost.

```
import os
import requests

os.environ['NO_PROXY'] = '127.0.0.1'
r = requests.get('http://127.0.0.1:8765')
print(r.content)
```

Once, you've done this you need to use the requests library and headers that are needed to pass in to get the data. In this case, the headers are audio and words files.